# How to convert any word into an integer in Python

Tags: python, list, encryption, data-conversion

Is there a possible way to convert any word, which is obviously in form of a string to an integer in python.

That might seem utterly stupid and impossible at first, but if you take a look at it, it's a good problem to work on that I have been struggling with so long.

And yes, I have tried many other ways such as using a list to store different integers to their corresponding letters, however; it didn't go very well.

Comment: You mean `hash` it? Else, you can interpret words as integer in base `26`.

Comment: Can you give an example? Replace each letter with its ASCII value works?

Comment: What do you mean? What would be the integer of the word "word"

Comment: Please clarify your question. What does "How to convert any word into an integer" even mean ? Give sample input and output. Casting a string to integer is not enough for you ? Why, etc...

Comment: [under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: `def convertWordToInteger(word): return 4` - converts any word (or any other object, for that matter) to an integer.  If you have further requirements (such as reversibility of the transformation), *you need to specify them*.

Comment: really sad that you don't respond to any posts of ppl who are wanting to help you :(

Comment: @B001ᛦ Will that method convert it into a literal integer? or will it be a string like: ("12"). We can also use the int() method to convert a string to an integer if it happens to be a valid number, right? (I am a newbie in python!) Sorry for being too late, i went offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in `hash` function:

```
>>> hash('hello')
-8733837932593682240
```

Comment: Potential problems: more than one word may hash to the same value. You can't determine the original word if all you have is the number. The hash for a string may change between two consecutive executions of the program.

Comment: But isn't it that, any 2 different words can correspond to same hashes? I don't know much about this as I am a newbie when it comes to python.

Comment: Yes, 2 different words can have the same hash. This is a complete certainty if you define a "word" as "any string containing any combination of characters". It's merely a near-certainty if you define "word" as "something appearing in an English dictionary"

Answer (score 2):

You could create a mapping between primes (2,3,5,7,... ) to all characters in your alphabet (a,b,c,d,e,...). Then you map the position of the character inside your word to the next bigger primes.

Then you multiply your character value with your positional value and sum all up:

Example:

```
alphabet = {"a":2, "b":3, "1":5, "2":7 }
position = [11,13,17,19,23,29,31]
text = "aabb12a"

def encode(t):
    """Throws error when not map-able"""
    return sum(alphabet[x] * position[pos] for pos,x in enumerate(t))


for i in alphabet:
    print(i,"=>",encode(i))

print(encode(text))
```

Output:

```
('a', '=>', 22)
('1', '=>', 55)
('2', '=>', 77)
('b', '=>', 33)
536
```

To reverse the number, you would have to do a prime factorisation, order the resuling summands by theire bigger number ascending, then reverse the mapping of your alphabet.

In this case you would get :

```
536 = 2*11 + 2*13 + 3*17 + 3*19 + 5*23+ 7*29 + 2*31
```

and you can lookup position and character to reconstruct your word.

Give, with 128 characters (ascii) and words up to 50 characters you would get *big* numbers....